# Redirection operator working in shell prompt but not not in script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a file called `out1.csv` which contains tabular data.
When I run the command in the terminal it works:

```
cat out1.csv | grep -v ^$ | grep -v ^- > out2.csv
```

It reads the file and greps all lines except blanks and starting with - and redirects the output to `out2.csv`.

But when I put the same command in a script it does not work. 
I have even tried echoing:

```
echo " `cat out1.csv | grep -v ^$ | grep -v ^- > out2.csv` " > out2.csv
```

I have also tried to specify full paths of the files. But no luck.

In the script, the command runs, but output is not redirected to the file as per debug mode.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "as per debug mode"?

Comment: @rghome  ksh -x script. sh

Comment: I know -x, but surely, the debug output does not go to the file either? I am not sure what the significance of your statement is.

Comment: @rghome The command works when directly typed in the shell prompt. But when I put the command in script.sh and run the script, it does not work. That is my issue.

Comment: As written, `cat out1.csv | grep -v ^$ | grep -v ^- > out2.csv` will work fine both at the command line  or in a script.  In order for us to figure out what is happening, you need to provide more details.  For example, "does not work" is vague.  Exactly, what is in your script?
How are you executing the script? What, precisely, happens when you run the script?  Are there error messages?

Comment: Please run `ksh -vx your-script` and paste the output into your question at the end.

Comment: Vote to close this due to lack of feedback and the fact it is obviously just a basic mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The issue wasn't of the script but of the sql script that this script was calling before this command.  Both commands are actually proper.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding an answer. You might also like to delete the question if it was a mistake.

Comment: @rghome Okay. I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it in script will be same as you do in console #BETTER WAY
`cat out1.csv | grep -v ^$ | grep -v ^- > out2.csv`   # No need to echo it or put the command in backtick `

## You are redirecting twice

The other way as you are trying is
echo " `cat out1.csv | grep -v ^$ | grep -v ^- > out2.csv` " # Don't redirect the output again to out2.csv

Comment: The question says they tried the first command in a script and it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

### You're redirecting twice

The command in backticks writes to file and prints nothing.

You take that nothing and write it to the file, overwriting what was there before.

Comment: The question says they tried the first command in a script and it did not work either.